# How to explode dataframe after groupby aggregation?

Tags: python-polars

A typical dataframe after a groupby might look like:

```
import polars as pl
pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series("chromosome", ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'], dtype=pl.Utf8),
        pl.Series("starts", [10, 1, 4, 7], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("ends", [11, 4, 5, 8], dtype=pl.Int64),
        pl.Series("starts_right", [[6, 8], [0, 5], [5, 0], [6, 5]], dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64)),
        pl.Series("ends_right", [[10, 9], [2, 7], [7, 2], [10, 7]], dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64)),
    ]
)

shape: (4, 5)
┌────────────┬────────┬──────┬──────────────┬────────────┐
│ chromosome ┆ starts ┆ ends ┆ starts_right ┆ ends_right │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---          ┆ ---        │
│ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64  ┆ list[i64]    ┆ list[i64]  │
╞════════════╪════════╪══════╪══════════════╪════════════╡
│ chr1       ┆ 10     ┆ 11   ┆ [6, 8]       ┆ [10, 9]    │
│ chr1       ┆ 1      ┆ 4    ┆ [0, 5]       ┆ [2, 7]     │
│ chr1       ┆ 4      ┆ 5    ┆ [5, 0]       ┆ [7, 2]     │
│ chr1       ┆ 7      ┆ 8    ┆ [6, 5]       ┆ [10, 7]    │
└────────────┴────────┴──────┴──────────────┴────────────┘
```

How do I explode the data frame in the least expensive way? So that each scalar entry is repeated twice and each item in each list is listed once as a scalar value, on its own row. I guess this operation is so common it should be built in somehow.

I.e.

```
┌────────────┬────────┬──────┬──────────────┬────────────┐
│ chromosome ┆ starts ┆ ends ┆ starts_right ┆ ends_right │
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---          ┆ ---        │
│ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64  ┆ i64          ┆ i64        │
╞════════════╪════════╪══════╪══════════════╪════════════╡
│ chr1       ┆ 10     ┆ 11   ┆ 6            ┆ 10         │
│ chr1       ┆ 10     ┆ 11   ┆ 8            ┆ 9          │
│ chr1       ┆ 1      ┆ 4    ┆ 0            ┆ 2          │
│ chr1       ┆ 1      ┆ 4    ┆ 5            ┆ 7          │
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polars indeed already has this. Just do .explode and pass the columns which you want to explode on.

```py
df.explode(['starts_right','ends_right'])
```

| chromosome | starts | ends | starts_right | ends_right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "chr1" | 10 | 11 | 6 | 10 |
| "chr1" | 10 | 11 | 8 | 9 |
| "chr1" | 1 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| "chr1" | 1 | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| "chr1" | 4 | 5 | 5 | 7 |
| "chr1" | 4 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| "chr1" | 7 | 8 | 6 | 10 |
| "chr1" | 7 | 8 | 5 | 7 |